# perform class interface parameter

Tags: abap

Is it possible to pass a class to perform immediately, bypassing the intermediate variable `xx`?

test code work

```
INTERFACE my_interface1.
  methods get_num returning value(rr) type i.
ENDINTERFACE.

CLASS num_counter Definition.
  PUBLIC Section.
    INTERFACES my_interface1.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS num_counter Implementation.
  Method my_interface1~get_num. 
    rr = 10.
  EndMethod.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  data c1 type ref to num_counter. 
  create object c1.

  data xx type ref to my_interface1.
  xx = c1.

  PERFORM test using xx.

"------------------------------------------
form test
    using
      aaa type ref to my_interface1.
  data xxi type i.
  xxi = aaa->get_num( ).
  WRITE xxi .
endform.
```

Instead, I'd like to directly do:

```
PERFORM test using c1.
```

but it was not working.

I also tried

```
PERFORM test using c1->my_interface1.
```

and

```
PERFORM test using c1~my_interface1.
```

but it was not working too.

ABAP 7.0

thanks

Comment: At run-time, a `USING` parameter behaves exactly the same as a `CHANGING` parameter. And there's exactly the same restriction as you describe with the `CHANGING` parameters of function modules and methods. I won't be able to explain the reason better than this [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2011/10/05/abap-trapdoors-type-lock-in/).

Comment: @Sandra Rossi, So what I want to do is not possible? only through an intermediate variable?

Comment: TL;DR the blog post: it's not possible with `USING` or `CHANGING`. Hopefully subroutines (`FORM` and `PERFORM`) have been obsolete since ABAP 7.02, so you'll avoid the issue by using a method and an IMPORTING parameter.